# how can i use ORM tool like My Generation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, orm, mygeneration

i downloaded MyGeneration from net. And run. it has got connection string. **"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Data Source=localhost "**

on the other hand;

my connection string : Data Source=.\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog=NetTanitimTest; Integrated Security=True

if i click save or connect button it throws to me connection error. Who used it can you hel p me?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, MyGeneration requires an OLEDB connection for schema discovery.

Try something like this:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase; Integrated Security=true;
```

MyGeneration, while a great tool, is not actively developed and the codebase is several years old.

I would recommend trying more contemporary alternatives.

The first that comes to mind is [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/). Is dead simple to implement and is extensible.